# Doubt in K-map rule (loops)

Tags: boolean-algebra

[image: Kmaps]

Is it possible to mark a loop in k-map as in second figure in above diagram (indicated in blue). According to my knowledge the first figure is correct.

---

[image: kmaps2]

Is figure 3 or 4 correct?

Note: Consider red bordered 4 cells as one loop and blue colored cells as second loop in above diagrams.

Comment: 2 is incorrect and 3 is incorrect, and only 1 and 4 are correct. But for case 3 and 4, the blue loop can be marked over the whole first row, where $C$ is false.

Comment: @peterwhy so 4 can be drawn for both the ways ? ( marking the whole first row and as i drawn in diagram) What if I continued it only up to third column?

Comment: Case 4 can be written as $A' + AC'$, and you can as well simplify that to $A' + C'$.